# How to do Vlook using index in R

Tags: r, vlookup

Transactions table(image attached below) has many items in 1 transaction. For Eg:- 1st transaction has 3 items (224, 43, 76 are ItemID) so data is there till column Col3. Similarly there is data till 5000 rows.

I have item table which has ItemID, Price and ProductName.

I need to replace numbers in Col0 to Col58 in transaction table with their respective ProductName based on ItemNo which is there in both the tables.

I have written the following code that replace the productName for Col0, since all the transactions have 1st item, we can get the product names.

However when I do the same for Col1 in transaction table, it ignores the values which don't have match. Hence it can't club the result back to the original transaction structure.

```
col1 <- sqldf("SELECT Trans2.Col0_01, lookupitem.ProductName FROM Trans2 INNER JOIN lookupitem ON Trans2.Col0_01 = lookupitem.Item")
Trans2$oneitem<-col1$ProductName

[Data Table - Transactions][1]
Index Col0  Col1 Col2........Col58
   1   224    43    76
   2   23     43
   3   34
   4   1      32

[Item Description][2]
ItemNo  Price   ProductName
   0   2.5    Cheese
   1   1.5    Apple
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following,

```
Transactions[,-1] <- apply(Transactions[,-1], 1:2, 
                         function(i) Description$ProductName[match(i, Description$ItemNo)])
```